# Crash...not able to trace because of inconsistency

Tags: ios, ipad

Here is the error from device..error is not consistent..like I am not facing it on my iPad but user is keep saying it happen to him many times..app crashed as soon as it is launched.
Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Incident Identifier: 44236112-151D-410F-B153-CB8CC1F06536
CrashReporter Key: 08725115e7c9e53feab87f9009d6b8ec91283252
Hardware Model: iPad1,1
Process: MyProject [2221]
Path: /var/mobile/Applications/FA21B5D6-A45A-4014-801D-C0B818A76A49/MyProject.app/MyProject
Identifier: MyProject
Version: ??? (???)
Code Type: ARM (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [1]

Date/Time: 2012-02-26 22:49:07.511 -0500
OS Version: iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000004
Crashed Thread: 7

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x359d9010 0x359d8000 + 4112
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x359d9206 0x359d8000 + 4614
2 CoreFoundation 0x3524f41c 0x351c2000 + 578588
3 CoreFoundation 0x3524e11a 0x351c2000 + 573722
4 CoreFoundation 0x351d14d6 0x351c2000 + 62678
5 CoreFoundation 0x351d139e 0x351c2000 + 62366
6 GraphicsServices 0x37164fe6 0x37161000 + 16358
7 UIKit 0x3136e73c 0x3133d000 + 202556
8 MyProject 0x0000206a 0x1000 + 4202
9 MyProject 0x00002028 0x1000 + 4136

Thread 1:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x359e9628 0x359d8000 + 71208
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a05ff2 0x359f2000 + 81906
2 MyProject 0x0036adb0 0x1000 + 3579312
3 MyProject 0x002819d0 0x1000 + 2623952
4 MyProject 0x002c7bcc 0x1000 + 2911180
5 MyProject 0x0036ab62 0x1000 + 3578722
6 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a01c16 0x359f2000 + 64534
7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a01ad0 0x359f2000 + 64208

Thread 2 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x359d93b4 0x359d8000 + 5044
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x32c2ce78 0x32c20000 + 52856
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x32c2cb96 0x32c20000 + 52118

Thread 3:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x359e9cd4 0x359d8000 + 72916
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359fc30a 0x359f2000 + 41738
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359fc09c 0x359f2000 + 41116

Thread 4:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x359e9cd4 0x359d8000 + 72916
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359fc30a 0x359f2000 + 41738
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359fc09c 0x359f2000 + 41116

Thread 5 name: WebThread
Thread 5:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x359d9010 0x359d8000 + 4112
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x359d9206 0x359d8000 + 4614
2 CoreFoundation 0x3524f41c 0x351c2000 + 578588
3 CoreFoundation 0x3524e154 0x351c2000 + 573780
4 CoreFoundation 0x351d14d6 0x351c2000 + 62678
5 CoreFoundation 0x351d139e 0x351c2000 + 62366
6 WebCore 0x32329128 0x32281000 + 688424
7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a01c16 0x359f2000 + 64534
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a01ad0 0x359f2000 + 64208

Thread 6 name: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x359d9010 0x359d8000 + 4112
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x359d9206 0x359d8000 + 4614
2 CoreFoundation 0x3524f41c 0x351c2000 + 578588
3 CoreFoundation 0x3524e154 0x351c2000 + 573780
4 CoreFoundation 0x351d14d6 0x351c2000 + 62678
5 CoreFoundation 0x351d139e 0x351c2000 + 62366
6 Foundation 0x32aaebc2 0x32a9e000 + 68546
7 Foundation 0x32aaea8a 0x32a9e000 + 68234
8 Foundation 0x32b4259a 0x32a9e000 + 673178
9 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a01c16 0x359f2000 + 64534
10 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a01ad0 0x359f2000 + 64208

Thread 7 name: Dispatch queue: com.DQ.SessionEstablishmentqueue1
Thread 7 Crashed:
0 MyProject 0x0025c7fc 0x1000 + 2471932
1 MyProject 0x0006199e 0x1000 + 395678
2 MyProject 0x0005fe78 0x1000 + 388728
3 libdispatch.dylib 0x32c20d4e 0x32c20000 + 3406
4 libdispatch.dylib 0x32c2bccc 0x32c20000 + 48332
5 libdispatch.dylib 0x32c2bb66 0x32c20000 + 47974
6 libdispatch.dylib 0x32c2c76c 0x32c20000 + 51052
7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359fc1c8 0x359f2000 + 41416
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359fc09c 0x359f2000 + 41116

Thread 8:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x359e9cd4 0x359d8000 + 72916
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359fc30a 0x359f2000 + 41738
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359fc09c 0x359f2000 + 41116

Thread 9 name: com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x359e9570 0x359d8000 + 71024
1 CoreFoundation 0x3525366a 0x351c2000 + 595562
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a01c16 0x359f2000 + 64534
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a01ad0 0x359f2000 + 64208

Thread 7 crashed with ARM Thread State:
r0: 0xffffffff r1: 0x03a8fcac r2: 0x00000000 r3: 0x03a8fccc
r4: 0x03a8fcb8 r5: 0x0025c725 r6: 0x03a90048 r7: 0x03a8fd38
r8: 0x00000000 r9: 0x00000000 r10: 0x00000000 r11: 0x00010001
ip: 0x004b0370 sp: 0x03a8fc34 lr: 0x0025c735 pc: 0x0025c7fc
cpsr: 0x60000030

Answer (score 2):

This is a shot in the dark, but I see that the thread that crashed is a dispatch queue.  I'm assuming you're using blocks to execute.  I had a problem with KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS because I was storing blocks (in an array, ivar, etc) but I had forgotten to copy them first. Any block that's stored (not passed directly to the execution) needs to be copied.  You can accomplish this by `[blockToCopy copy];` or `Block_copy()`.

Comment: Yes I am using blocks to execute my Connection module..at-least ur suggestion gives me direction to look for fix.

Answer (score 0):

That is difficult to read, but you can view crash logs agains the compiled binary.

"With the latest version of Xcode (3.2.2), you can drag and drop any crash reports into the Device Logs section of the Xcode Organiser and they will automatically by symbolicated for you. I think this works best if you built that version of the App using Build & Archive (also part of Xcode 3.2.2)"

[Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

that is certainly easier then looking at the crash log with no source to work with.

Comment: Problem for me is crash report is of user, I don't have his device logs with me or to simply put I can hook in his iPad and check what is wrong here.

Comment: Im not sure if this is any more helpful, but you could use TestFlight to get the logs back, this is mostly for beta testing, but maybe for this difficult case you might consider it.